# Magento 2: Checkout 503 or 404

Tags: magento2, checkout

I am facing one issue and trying to find it solution form a long time. But still unable to find the solution

In our live site, the server has one backend and four frontend servers.
while checkout we get the errors and when I debug I found

> https://BASEURL/static/version1568090061/frontend/xxx/xxx/STORE/Magento_Checkout/js/action/set-shipping-information.min.js and https://BASEURL/STORE/rest/STORE/V1/guest-carts/5a7b7d15090f56fde5477e0b649d536a/set-payment-information return 404

When I search then I think this issue may be occurring because of a sticky session. so I ask the server hosting company to enable sticky session then the error came 503. When I debug the message I found it also return the server down the message with the JSON response. I am wondering, I am the only one who is facing this issue or anyone else have also faced this issue. I am using Magento EE 2.2.2

**Note:** This issue occurs more often If I use the `Onestep Checkout extension` and `chrome`. And in my staging server where there is only one server for backend and frontend this issue does not occur.